# Does it make a difference to run xgboost on hot encoded variables or single factor variable?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, python, boosting

I have a dataset, that has a categorical "products" column. It has some 1000 distinct values.

Can I directly convert it to integers (say 1-1000) and use this column as a single variable or should I convert it to dummy coding 1/0 for all products as columns? Does it make a difference?

Comment: And you could also use individual 10 binary bits, since $1000<=2^{10}$. And you could reorder/encode the categorical levels (e.g. target mean encoding), to make the individual levels or binary bits more aligned with which subset of values are being used in splits.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it makes a difference. There is no good answer, you should try both. If you are looking for performance, you may even need to try various encodings and stack the models with the different ecodings...

Another approach could be to replace the factors (with a relatively large number of occurences) by the conditional average value of the target.

**Edit.**

As for the why, the reason comes from the fact that boosting are based on decision trees.

Imagine the factor column represents a country. If you encode it as an integer, the decision rule will read as `if country > 10`. This groups will represent all the countries that do not correspond to the first 10 countries (and the order of encoding will matter).

On the other hand, if you encode it with dummy variables, the generated rules will be `if country10 > 0.5` (and this may correspond to a specific country : `country10 == 1`). Now (if you don't subsamble the columns when growing a tree), the performance of the model will be the same regardless of the encoding.

**Towards an optimal integer encoding ?**

Do you have information on the products ? Or is it just an ID ? If you could range your products so that 1-100 are, say, cellphones, 101-300 cars, 301 - 1000 books, it may help your algorithm to find groups with an actual meaning (now the rule `if product > 300` automatically refers to all the books... There is absolutely no guarantees of improvement of performance with this method though.

Comment: Why does it make a difference? This answer could benefit from some explanation.

Comment: The reason, why I asked is, because, I have seen people getting more accuracy, just by changing to 1/0 encoding instead of single variable coding

Comment: @muni this is completely possible... Especially if no specific treatment was performed when the labels were encoded with integers

Comment: Hi @RUser4512, Is it true that "the more variable the better" for XGBoost? Because for each tree growth, the tree select the variable with a maximum gain. Even if I added noise variables, the tree still should select the same variable, right? Thanks.

Comment: @Frank no, indeed, too many (noisy) variables will probably harm the performance...

Comment: @RUser4512: Interesting, please add citations. As you add more variables to encode the same amount of information, you reduce the amount of information in each variable. There's also a middle-ground where you could decompose one column with 1000 values into (say) two levels with 32*32 variables, or (say) three levels with 10*10*10 variables (as WCMC pointed out). I'm guessing the 'optimal' encoding could be found by looking at conditional-densities of this variable ('products') together with whatever other high-importance variables are used in the tree, then reencode 'products' variable

Comment: @WCMC: absolutely not, because **a (categorical) variable with 2^n levels contains the same amount of information, regardless whether we encode it as one integer, n bits, 2^n one-hot variables, or any other encoding (such as reordering the level values)**. In fact the more variables we use to encode the *same* one single feature, the *less* information each of those individual variables carries, hence the less likely it is to be picked by the tree.